# Modeling of Systems Using Flux Balance Analysis - Metabolites Can't Introduced to System (CobraPY)

Tags: python, modeling

This is both mathematics, modeling and biology.

Using flux balance analysis we are modeling systems.

I have a reaction with steps in our CobraPY model that is in essence this:

A + B --> C

C + D --> E

E + F --> G

The problem is that D is a protein that is impossible to model the creation of. Are there any workarounds for groups and flux balance analysis that allow the brief introduction of a protein or other metabolite then remove it from the system? I assume it would create infinite mass or a loop of some kind.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older question, but a good one for other people to understand, even if it might be better on a biology forum.

Constrained-based modeling and flux balance analysis are based on stoichiometric models where all reactions must be mass balanced, so proteins and enzymes are hard to model. But what I can interpret from your situation the protein labeled "D" is being consumed, so there must be a reaction that is creating it. In FBA, we model proteins as metabolites all the time; think of Cytochrome C or Ferredoxin, where a reaction consumes reduced Ferredoxin and then produces oxidized ferredoxin so that the total equation is mass balanced.

If your protein "D" contributes to the reaction (like donating electrons, or a methyl group, etc.), you can make your protein a metabolite and create a reaction to form it.

See this tutorial (https://cobrapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/building_model.html#Model,-Reactions-and-Metabolites)

The last part of your question, "allow the brief introduction of a protein or other metabolite then remove it from the system" is another limitation with FBA where we always assume the system is in a steady state. So the introduction of metabolite for a specific "time chunk" does not work. Other techniques can help with that question, such as dynamicFBA and kinetic modeling.

So if it is anyway possible to find the reaction that produces your protein D I would right your reactions like so:

A + B --> C

X + D_0 -> D_1

C + D_1 --> E + D_0

E + F --> G

This will be a great question to be transferred to https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/125068/synthetic-biology when it is useable.